# Overloading member function among multiple base classes

Tags: c++, overloading, multiple-inheritance, ambiguous, name-lookup

Basically I want to have multiple member functions with same name, but different signature, spread in multiple base classes.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    void print(int) { std::cout << "Got an int!" << std::endl; }
};

struct B
{
    void print(double) { std::cout << "Got a double!" << std::endl; }
};

struct C : A, B {};

int main()
{
    C c;
    c.print((int)0);

    return 0;
};
```

But I got this error on clang:

```
main.cpp:18:7: error: member 'print' found in multiple base classes of different types
    c.print((int)0);
      ^
main.cpp:5:10: note: member found by ambiguous name lookup
    void print(int) { std::cout << "Got an int!" << std::endl; }
         ^
main.cpp:10:10: note: member found by ambiguous name lookup
    void print(double) { std::cout << "Got a double!" << std::endl; }
```

Why is it ambiguous? Even with different number of arguments I get the same error.

Is there any workaround to get similar behavior?

Comment: "`c.print((int)0)`" `0` is a literal of type `int`, you don't need to add `(int)` here

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use a `using` declaration in the derived class - it will fix your issues. It makes both overloads <del>visible and</del> viable to participate in the resolution.

```
struct C : A, B {
    using A::print;
    using B::print;
};
```

To answer why this is ambiguous: it is actually not about *visibility*, but about the inability to *participate in* the overload resolution, due to not being defined in the same scope. The `using` declaration pulls those methods in the `C` scope, so both of them become valid overloading resolution options.

Thanks to **@Pete Becker** for participating in this answer and pretty much creating this paragraph.

Comment: Both versions of `print` are visible in th derived class without the `using` directive. The problem is that they are not overloads because they are not defined in the same scope the `using` directive pulls both names into the derived class, and because of that, they are overloads. +1.

Comment: @PeteBecker this is a really good explanation - please, let me add it to my answer. I didn't include it originally simply because I wasn't sure whether my thought process is correct (it actually was kinda off). Thank you

Comment: @ElProfesor care to elaborate on the edit? The standard says that it's called a "*`using` directive*" (`9.7.3` - `[namespace.udir]`).

Comment: @Fureeish See point 6 in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace btw, you called it *using declaration* at the very beginning as well.

Comment: `using` directive --> `using namespace ...`

Comment: Thank you for the sources, rolled back to your edit