# Generate one method per type from variadic class template

Tags: c++11, methods, overloading, abstract-class, variadic-templates

I would like to have a variadic class template to generate one method per type, such that for example a class template like the following:

```
template <class T, class ... Ts>
class MyClass {
public:
    virtual void hello(const T& t) = 0;
};
```

would  make available the methods `hello(const double&)` and `hello(const int&)` when instantiated as  `MyClass<double, int> myclass;`

Note that I want the class to be pure abstract, such that a derived class would actually need to do the implementation, e.g.:

```
class Derived : MyClass<double, int> {
public:
    inline void hello(const double& t) override { }
    inline void hello(const int& t) override { }
};
```

This problem is somewhat similar [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941661/generating-one-class-member-per-variadic-template-argument), but I couldn't understand how to adapt it to my case.

**EDIT**

The recursion inheritance seems to be the right solution for me. How about this more complicated case, where the superclass has more than one method and a template argument is mandatory? Here is what I've tried (but I get error):

```
template <class MandatoryT, class OptionalT, class... MoreTs>
class MyClass : public MyClass<MandatoryT, MoreTs...> {
public:
    virtual ~MyClass() {}

    virtual char* goodmorning(const MandatoryT& t) = 0;

    virtual bool bye(const MandatoryT& t,
                     const std::map<std::string,bool>& t2) = 0;

  using MyClass<MandatoryT, MoreTs...>::hello;
  virtual void hello(const OptionalT& msg) = 0;
};


template <class MandatoryT, class OptionalT>
class MyClass<MandatoryT, OptionalT> {
  virtual void processSecondaryMessage(const OptionalT& msg) = 0;
};

template <class MandatoryT>
class MyClass<MandatoryT> {
  virtual void processSecondaryMessage() = 0;
}
}
```

Basically what I want is that the derived class should have one or more types. The first one is used in other methods, while from the second onwards it should be used in `hello()`. If only one type is provided, an empty `hello()` is called. But when at least a second type is provided, `hello()` should use it.

The code above complains that there should be at least two template arguments, because there are "two" ground cases instead of one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe someone else can do better, but I see only two ways

1. **Recursion inheritance**

   You can define `MyClass` recursively as follows

   ```
   // recursive case
   template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
   struct MyClass : public MyClass<Ts...>
    {
      using MyClass<Ts...>::hello;

      virtual void hello (const T&) = 0;
    };

   // ground case
   template <typename T>
   struct MyClass<T>
    { virtual void hello (const T&) = 0; };
   ```

or

2. **variadic inheritance**

   You can define another class/struct, say `MyHello`, that declare a
   single `hello()` method, and variadic inherit it from `MyClass`.

   ```
   template <typename T>
   struct MyHello
    { virtual void hello (const T&) = 0; };

   template <typename ... Ts>
   struct MyClass : public MyHello<Ts>...
    { };
   ```

The recursive example is compatible with type collision (that is: works also when a type is present more time in the list of template arguments `MyClass`; by example `MyClass<int, double, int>`).

The variadic inheritance case, unfortunately, isn't.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#if 1
// recursive case
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct MyClass : public MyClass<Ts...>
 {
   using MyClass<Ts...>::hello;

   virtual void hello (const T&) = 0;
 };

// ground case
template <typename T>
struct MyClass<T>
 { virtual void hello (const T&) = 0; };
#else

template <typename T>
struct MyHello
 { virtual void hello (const T&) = 0; };

template <typename ... Ts>
struct MyClass : public MyHello<Ts>...
 { };

#endif

struct Derived : public MyClass<double, int>
 {
   inline void hello (const double&) override { }
   inline void hello (const int&) override { }
 };

int main()
 {
   Derived d;

   d.hello(1.0);
   d.hello(2);
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP asks

> how about a more complicated case where MyClass has more than one method and I always need to have one template argument (see edited question)?

From your question I don't understand what do you exactly want.

But supposing you want a pure virtual method, say `goodmorning()` that receive a `MandT` (the mandatory type), a pure virtual method `hello()` for every type following `MandT` or an `hello()` without arguments when the list after `MandT` is empty.

A possible solution is the following

```
// declaration and groundcase with only mandatory type (other cases
// intecepted by specializations)
template <typename MandT, typename ...>
struct MyClass
 {
   virtual void hello () = 0;

   virtual ~MyClass () {}

   virtual char * goodmorning (MandT const &) = 0;
 };

// groundcase with a single optional type
template <typename MandT, typename OptT>
struct MyClass<MandT, OptT>
 {
   virtual void hello (OptT const &) = 0;

   virtual ~MyClass () {}

   virtual char * goodmorning (MandT const &) = 0;
 };

// recursive case
template <typename MandT, typename OptT, typename ... MoreOptTs>
struct MyClass<MandT, OptT, MoreOptTs...>
   : public MyClass<MandT, MoreOptTs...>
 {
   using MyClass<MandT, MoreOptTs...>::hello;

   virtual void hello (OptT const &) = 0;

   virtual ~MyClass () {}
 };
```

Here the recursion is a little more complicated than before.

In case you instantiate a `MyClass` with only the mandatory type (by example: `MyClass<char>`) the main version ("groundcase with only mandatory type") is selected because the two specialization doesn't match (no first optional type).

In case you instantiate a `Myclass` with one optional type (say `MyClass<char, double>`) the specialization "groundcase with a single optional type" is selected because is the most specialized version.

In case you instantiate a `MyClass` with two or more optional type (say `MyClass<char, double, int>` start recursion (last specialization) until remain an single optional type (so the "groundcase with a single optional type" is selected).

Observe that I've placed the `goodmorning()` in both ground cases, because you don't need to define it recursively.

The following is a full compiling example

```
// declaration and groundcase with only mandatory type (other cases
// intecepted by specializations)
template <typename MandT, typename ...>
struct MyClass
 {
   virtual void hello () = 0;

   virtual ~MyClass () {}

   virtual char * goodmorning (MandT const &) = 0;
 };

// groundcase with a single optional type
template <typename MandT, typename OptT>
struct MyClass<MandT, OptT>
 {
   virtual void hello (OptT const &) = 0;

   virtual ~MyClass () {}

   virtual char * goodmorning (MandT const &) = 0;
 };

// recursive case
template <typename MandT, typename OptT, typename ... MoreOptTs>
struct MyClass<MandT, OptT, MoreOptTs...>
   : public MyClass<MandT, MoreOptTs...>
 {
   using MyClass<MandT, MoreOptTs...>::hello;

   virtual void hello (OptT const &) = 0;

   virtual ~MyClass () {}
 };


struct Derived0 : public MyClass<char>
 {
   void hello () override { }

   char * goodmorning (char const &) override
    { return nullptr; }
 };
struct Derived1 : public MyClass<char, double>
 {
   void hello (double const &) override { }

   char * goodmorning (char const &) override
    { return nullptr; }
 };

struct Derived2 : public MyClass<char, double, int>
 {
   void hello (double const &) override { }
   void hello (int const &) override { }

   char * goodmorning (char const &) override
    { return nullptr; }
 };



int main()
 {
   Derived0  d0;
   Derived1  d1;
   Derived2  d2;

   d0.hello();
   d0.goodmorning('a');

   d1.hello(1.2);
   d1.goodmorning('b');

   d2.hello(3.4);
   d2.hello(5);
   d2.goodmorning('c');
 }
```

Comment: The second version with variadic inheritance also has the benefit that `MyHello<T>` can be used as an interface.

Comment: @aschepler - yes... I'm trying to make it work but I have some compiler errors (I'm a disaster with virtual inheritance).

Comment: I don't see how virtual inheritance would help here.

Comment: @aschepler - sorry... I've misunderstood your "variadic" with "virtual"; the problem I'm trying to solve is the case of type collisions in `Ts...` list; for recursive version isn't a problem but with virtual inheritance there is collision; I'm trying with virtual inheritance but doesn't works.

Comment: You mean if a type appears twice, like `MyClass<int, double, int>`?

Comment: @aschepler - exactly.

Comment: I'd probably just document that's invalid. Or if there's reason to support it, I'd attempt to work in something that filters out duplicates to determine the actual base class list.

Comment: The variadic inheritance version has one additional slight problem. [It doesn't work at all](https://ideone.com/p7pPYE).

Comment: @n.m. - I didn't know at all this problem that, if I understand correctly, is the same of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51690394/overloading-member-function-among-multiple-base-classes). In your code can be easily solved adding `using MyHello<Ts>::hello...;` in `MyClass` but, unfortunately, variadic `using` is available only starting from C++17 (if I remember correctly). Anyway, taking in count that (for this question) the it's necessary override the functions in `MyClass`, this shouldn't be a problem (in this case).

Comment: Overriding it in the derived class solves the ambiguity for the derived class. When you have a virtual fcn you normally want to call it via a base class pointer/ref. I didn't know about variadic using, it is neat.

Comment: Thank you @max66, I haven't completely understood your solution because in order to understand recursion you first need to understand recursion...how about a more complicated case where `MyClass` has more than one method and I always need to have one template argument (see edited question)?

Comment: @MarcoCamurri - Yes... recursion is a little complicated sometime. Anyway, I've improved the answer trying to respond to your edit (with a more complicated recursion example; sorry).

Comment: @max66 you are a genius and you win.